# Xirsys signalling server wrong message

Tags: websocket, webrtc, xirsys

I'm sending json message to Xirsys signalling server

Message structure (original message):

```
userid: 'username',
type: 'type',
room: 'roomname',
message: {
    targetUserId: 'userid',
    eventName: 'event',
    data: {
        offer: {<some data>},
        connectionId: 'conn_id'
    }
}
```

On the other side I'm getting this message wrapped to strange object:

```
{
    "userid":"qwe",
    "type":"receiveanswer",
    "room":"default",
    "message":{<original message>}
}
```

[send() (link to github)](https://github.com/xirdev/xsdk/blob/master/lib/xirsys.signal.js#L393)

This is the function where I've changed `service_pkt` object structure and then I'm sending this object using `this.sock.send(pkt)

Why am I getting wrapped message?

Answer (score 1):

The v1 Xirsys websocket protocol uses framing based on certain event types to provide additional data to the receiver.  You are better off using the newer Xirsys websocket protocol, which has a more flexible API.  You can see how it works by looking at the xirsys.signal.js file in the following repo:

https://github.com/xirdev/xsdk

The new v3 platform, currently in beta, will be providing detailed documentation about the socket protocols in the new release.

Comment: Thanks Lee, now it makes sense.